# dplyr/data.table: How to calculate the mean for counts of observations per group for two vectors containing factors in R

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, data.table, mean

**Issue**

I want to conduct a chi-square test on my data to explore if there are statistical differences between `whistle types (A-F)` amongst countries `'France' and 'Germany'` (**see the reproducible data frame below**).

I would like to produce a table exactly the same as the `Whistle Type Count table` (see below) but instead of the counts of observations per whistle type, I would like to calculate the mean of each whistle type(A-F) per country using either the packages `dplyr` or `data.table`. Both the vectors `Country` and `Whistle Type` are factors.

For this analysis, I cannot figure out how to calculate the mean for each whistle type per country.

If anyone is able to help, I would like to thank you in advance.

**Whistle Type Count Table**

```
library(dplyr)

#Count the number of Whistle types per country
Count_Whistle.type <- Whistle_Parameters %>% dplyr::count(Whistle_Type, Country, sort=TRUE)

Counts of Observations per whistle type 

   Whistle_Type Country  n
1             F Germany 38
2             E  France 37
3             B  France 33
4             C Germany 33
5             B Germany 31
6             A  France 27
7             F  France 27
8             A Germany 25
9             D  France 23
10            C  France 21
11            D Germany 21
12            E Germany 19
```

**What I need is something like this (these mean values are made up) showing the mean for each whistle type per country**

```
   Whistle_Type Country  Mean
1             F Germany 14.9
2             E  France 12.4
3             B  France  9.6
```

**Reproducible R Code**

```
#Dummy data
#Create a cluster column with dummy data (clusters = 3)
f1 <- gl(n = 2, k=167.5); f1

#Produce a data frame for the dummy level data
f2<-as.data.frame(f1)

#Rename the column f2
colnames(f2)<-"Country"

#How many rows
nrow(f2)

#Rename the levels of the dependent variable 'Country' as classifiers
#prefer the inputs to be factors
levels(f2$Country) <- c("France", "Germany")

#Add a vector called Whistle Types
#Add a vector called Behaviors
Whistle_Types<-sample(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                     'E', 'F'), 335, replace=TRUE)

#Create random numbers
Start.Freq<-runif(335, min=1.195110e+02, max=23306.000000)
End.Freq<-runif(335, min=3.750000e+02, max=65310.000000)
Delta.Time<-runif(335, min=2.192504e-02, max=3.155762)
Low.Freq<-runif(335, min=6.592500e+02, max=20491.803000)
High.Freq<-runif(335, min=2.051000e+03, max=36388.450000)
Peak.Freq<-runif(335, min=7.324220+02, max=35595.703000)
Center.Freq<-runif(335, min=2.190000e-02, max=3.155800)
Delta.Freq<-runif(335, min=1.171875+03, max=30761.719000)
Delta.Time<-runif(335, min=2.192504e-02, max=3.155762)

#Bind the columns together
Bind<-cbind(f2, Start.Freq, End.Freq,  Low.Freq, High.Freq, Peak.Freq,  Center.Freq, Delta.Freq, Delta.Time, Whistle_Types)

#Rename the columns 
colnames(Bind)<-c('Country', 'Low.Freq', 'High.Freq', 'Start.Freq', 'End.Freq', 'Peak.Freq', 'Center.Freq', 
                  'Delta.Freq', 'Delta.Time',"Whistle_Type")

#Produce a dataframe
Whistle_Parameters<-as.data.frame(Bind)
Whistle_Parameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Whistle_Parameters)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=T), .(Country, Whistle_Type)]
```

OR

```
library(dplyr)
Whistle_Parameters %>% 
  group_by(Country, Whistle_Type) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), mean))
```

Comment: Hello, Langtang. Thank you so much for answering my question. This is excellent. Would you know how to calculate the mean number of whistle types per country?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Each country in your example data has 6 Whistle Types. What average/mean are you talking about?

Comment: For instance, the mean number of whistle counts for whistle type A for Germany for instance and then for France. I would like to do this for all whistle types. I can use count() to count the number of observations per whistle type but I don't know how to calculate the mean for each Whistle type for each country in the same lines of code. Many thanks if you can help.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense.. What is the mean of Whistle Type A for France?  Mean of what?

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table`:

```
setDT(Whistle_Parameters)
# vector of variable to average
var_to_mean <- setdiff(names(Whistle_Parameters),c("Country","Whistle_Type"))
# mean per Country and Whistle_type, for each column
Whistle_Parameters[,lapply(.SD,mean),.SDcols = var_to_mean,by = .(Country,Whistle_Type)]

   Country Whistle_Type Low.Freq High.Freq Start.Freq End.Freq Peak.Freq Center.Freq Delta.Freq Delta.Time
 1:  France            B 12518.44  31489.32  11258.852 20716.42  17208.48    1.527760   12618.33   1.851037
 2:  France            C 10843.06  36625.38  10069.604 18183.59  18561.31    1.628858   15495.80   1.485466
 3:  France            F 11232.58  31955.38  10833.592 20992.41  19007.11    1.562517   17165.26   1.729563
 4:  France            E 10418.82  34813.67  11325.300 15257.26  17749.05    1.614468   18908.37   1.549006
 5:  France            D 14526.32  29232.38  10738.944 16636.51  16756.75    2.004199   14306.67   1.608868
 6:  France            A 14378.98  37006.09  10261.817 16479.82  18099.49    1.467998   12310.01   1.538442
 7: Germany            C 10866.43  40694.70  10420.398 16017.48  17431.95    1.721555   14245.38   1.195733
 8: Germany            E 14830.39  38750.77  10313.795 19415.02  20879.32    1.808080   17165.47   1.207900
 9: Germany            F 11270.00  27803.95  10173.037 19908.47  18155.31    1.375614   13727.61   1.528704
10: Germany            B 12186.73  30519.04   9743.094 17460.80  19031.94    1.700328   17530.92   1.782998
11: Germany            A 11639.71  34723.41  10769.073 18420.37  13990.86    1.485000   15683.72   1.488470
12: Germany            D 12461.53  41251.08   8739.983 21661.02  15025.17    1.515318   12918.67   1.516498
```

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

Whistle_Parameters %>%
  group_by(Country,Whistle_Type) %>%
  summarise(across(var_to_mean,mean))

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Country'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 12 x 10
# Groups:   Country [2]
   Country Whistle_Type Low.Freq High.Freq Start.Freq End.Freq Peak.Freq Cente~1 Delta~2 Delta~3
   <fct>   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 France  A              14379.    37006.     10262.   16480.    18099.    1.47  12310.    1.54
 2 France  B              12518.    31489.     11259.   20716.    17208.    1.53  12618.    1.85
 3 France  C              10843.    36625.     10070.   18184.    18561.    1.63  15496.    1.49
 4 France  D              14526.    29232.     10739.   16637.    16757.    2.00  14307.    1.61
 5 France  E              10419.    34814.     11325.   15257.    17749.    1.61  18908.    1.55
 6 France  F              11233.    31955.     10834.   20992.    19007.    1.56  17165.    1.73
 7 Germany A              11640.    34723.     10769.   18420.    13991.    1.49  15684.    1.49
 8 Germany B              12187.    30519.      9743.   17461.    19032.    1.70  17531.    1.78
 9 Germany C              10866.    40695.     10420.   16017.    17432.    1.72  14245.    1.20
10 Germany D              12462.    41251.      8740.   21661.    15025.    1.52  12919.    1.52
11 Germany E              14830.    38751.     10314.   19415.    20879.    1.81  17165.    1.21
12 Germany F              11270.    27804.     10173.   19908.    18155.    1.38  13728.    1.53
```

Comment: Hey Dennis. Thank you so much, this is excellent. Would you happen to know how to calculate the mean number of whistle types per country? Many thanks if you can help

Comment: `Whistle_Parameters[,.(N_whistle_type = uniqueN(Whistle_Type)),Country][,mean(N_whistle_type)]`

Comment: `Whistle_Parameters %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarise(N_whistle_type = length(unique(Whistle_Type)))%>%
  pull(N_whistle_type) %>%
  mean

`